# kendo ng-delay with page refresh on dropdownlist causes list contents to disappear

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm trying to rewrite a knockout + jQuery UI web app as a kendo + angular web app as a learning exercise.

I'm having a problem with a kendo-drop-down-list element that is populated with data from an ajax call.  I use the `k-ng-delay` to watch for config.dataSource variable, which gets assigned in the success-callback of the $http GET. Everything works as expected. However, if the user refreshes the page, the contents of the dropdownlist disappear.

I searched around and found a document (not current) that said to use `k-rebind`, but watching config.dataSource with k-rebind causes angular to crash.

What is the proper way to handle this page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. `k-ng-delay` worked very unstable for me. You can use `k-rebind`, but bind to the other controller variable, not the same that `k-options` is bound, for example for grid with foreign key in view:

```
<div
            kendo-grid
            k-options="vm.gridOptions"
            k-rebind="vm.gridBound">
    </div>
```

In controller after the gridOptions initialization:

```
vm.gridBound = true;
```